error 500 : internal server error : Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
i'm working on a spring boot angular application , i'm trying to create an update method in angular but all i get is an error 500 : internal server error , when i check my backend it shows this error:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
it seems like the frontend sends a request with a null object, here is my code : spring boot:
DTO:
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_type")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class ICanServiceType extends SimpleAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9097057735800769036L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "numeric_id", nullable = false)
    private int numericId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "min_fw_version")
    private String minFwVersion;

    @Column(name = "compat1")
    private Boolean compat1;

    @Column(name = "compat2")
    private Boolean compat2;

    @Column(name = "compat3")
    private Boolean compat3;

    @Column(name = "compat4")
    private Boolean compat4;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "serviceType")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Model> models;

Repo:
public interface ServiceTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ServiceType, Long> {


    Page<ServiceType> findAll(Pageable pageable);

 Optional<ServiceType> findOneByNumericId(Integer numericId);
}

Service:
@Service
public class ServiceTypeServiceV2 {

    private final ServiceTypeRepository ServiceTypeRepository;

    @Inject
    public ServiceTypeServiceV2(ServiceTypeRepository ServiceTypeRepository, FirmwareServiceV2 firmwareServiceV2, DeviceRepository deviceRepository) {
        this.ServiceTypeRepository = ServiceTypeRepository;
        this.firmwareServiceV2 = firmwareServiceV2;
        this.deviceRepository = deviceRepository;
    }

    public Page<ServiceType> getServiceTyp(Pageable pageable) {
        return ServiceTypeRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

   


  @Transactional
    public void updateServiceType(
            String name,
            Integer numericId,
            String minVersion,
            Boolean compat1,
            Boolean compat2,
            Boolean compat3,
            Boolean compat4) {

        ServiceType ServiceType = ServiceTypeRepository.findOneByNumericId(numericId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CrudException(Errors.SERVICETYPE_UNKNOWN, "Numeric Id", numericId.toString()));

        ServiceType.setName(name);
        ServiceType.setNumericId(numericId);
        ServiceType.setMinFwVersion(minVersion);
        ServiceType.setCompat1(compat1);
        ServiceType.setCompat2(compat2);
        ServiceType.setCompat3(compat3);
        ServiceType.setCompat4(compat4);
        ServiceTypeRepository.save(ServiceType);

        deviceRepository.updateIcanServiceTypeParameterLabel(DEVICE_TYPE.TYPES, numericId, name);
    }
  
}


Controller:

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v2/services")
@Tag(name = "/v2/services", description = "Service types for ican management")
@SecurityRequirement(name = OpenAPIConfiguration.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)
public class ServicetypeRessourceV2 {

 @Operation(summary = "Get all service types", description = "Returns the list of available service types")
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = ServiceTypeV2DTO.class))
    })
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized")
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize(AccessRightConstants.SERVICETYPE_READ_PERMISSION)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ServiceTypeV2DTO>> get(Pageable pageable) { 
        log.debug("REST request to get service types");
      
        Page<ServiceType> serviceTypes = ServiceTypeServiceV2.getServiceTyp(pageable);

        List<ServiceTypeV2DTO> serviceTypeV2DTOS = serviceTypes.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(ServiceType::getNumericId))
                .map(DtoFactory::createServiceTypeV2DTO)
                .toList();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(serviceTypeV2DTOS);

    }


   @Operation(summary = "Update service type", description = "Update service type and Returns the list of available service types")
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = ServiceTypeV2DTO.class))
    })
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized")
    @PutMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize(AccessRightConstants.SERVICETYPE_UPDATE_PERMISSION)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ServiceTypeV2DTO>> update(@RequestBody ServiceTypeV2DTO serviceTypeV2DTO) {

        log.debug("REST request to update service type");
        ServiceTypeServiceV2.updateServiceType(
                serviceTypeV2DTO.getName(),
                serviceTypeV2DTO.getValue(),
                serviceTypeV2DTO.getMinFwVersion(),
                serviceTypeV2DTO.getCompat1(),
                serviceTypeV2DTO.getCompat2(),
                serviceTypeV2DTO.getCompat3(),
                serviceTypeV2DTO.getCompat4()
        );


        Page<ServiceType> serviceTypes = ServiceTypeServiceV2.getServiceTyp(Pageable.unpaged()); //

        List<ServiceTypeV2DTO> serviceTypeV2DTOS = serviceTypes.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(ServiceType::getNumericId))
                .map(DtoFactory::createServiceTypeV2DTO)
                .toList();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(serviceTypeV2DTOS);
    }
}

angular front end : service.ts:
export class Servicetypeservice{

    private readonly SERVICE_TYPE_CONTEXT= `${AppConstants.CONTEXT}v2/services` ;
  //  private readonly port_service = 'http://localhost:8090/api/admin/v2/services';
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }


    GetAll(params): Observable<any[]>{
        return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(`${this.SERVICE_TYPE_CONTEXT}`,{params});
    }



 UpdateService(servicetype: any): Observable<ServiceType>{
        return this.httpClient.put<any>(`${(this.SERVICE_TYPE_CONTEXT)}` , {servicetype})
    }


component.ts:
export class ServiceManagementComponent implements OnInit {


    page: number = 1;
    pageSize: number = 10;
   pageSizes = [3,6,9];
    services : ServiceType[] = [];
    currentService: [] =[] ;
    currentIndex = -1;
    name = '';



    selectedIndex = -1;
    editmode = false;
    serviceType: ServiceType [];
    selectedService: ServiceType; //=null
    // currentService: ServiceType = {};



    serv = null;
 //   currentService : ServiceType={...serviceType[]};


    count = 0;

    totalItems: number = 256;

    serviceTypeForm: FormGroup


    constructor(private serviceTypeV2: Servicetypeservice) {
    } 
    ngOnInit(): void {
      
     this.loadServicesV2();
       

        // this.select(this.serviceType,0);

        this.serviceTypeForm = this.formBuilder.group({}, null);
        this.serviceTypeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            ID: [''],
            Name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\- ]*$"), Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(255)]],
            MinFwVersion: ['', Validators.required],
            Compat1: ['', Validators.required],
            Compat2: ['', Validators.required],
            Compat3: ['', Validators.required],
            Compat4: ['', Validators.required]
        }, null);


    }

  editServiceType() {
        this.editmode = !this.editmode;

    }

    selectedServiceTypeToForm(): void {
        if (this.selectedService != null) {
            this.serviceTypeForm.patchValue({
                ID: this.selectedService.value,
                Name: this.selectedService.name,
                MinFwVersion: this.selectedService.minFwVersion,
                Compat1: this.selectedService.compat1,
                Compat2: this.selectedService.compat2,
                Compat3: this.selectedService.compat3,
                Compat4: this.selectedService.compat4,
            });
        }
    }

formToSelectedService(): void {

        if (this.selectedService != null) {

            this.selectedService.value = this.serviceTypeForm.get('ID').value;
            this.selectedService.name = this.serviceTypeForm.get('Name').value;
            this.selectedService.minFwVersion = this.serviceTypeForm.get('MinFwVersion').value;
            this.selectedService.compat1 = this.serviceTypeForm.get('Compat1').value;
            this.selectedService.compat2 = this.serviceTypeForm.get('Compat2').value;
            this.selectedService.compat3 = this.serviceTypeForm.get('Compat3').value;
            this.selectedService.compat4 = this.serviceTypeForm.get('Compat4').value;

        }
    }


   loadServicesV2(){
        const params = this.getRequestParams(this.page, this.pageSize);
    this.serviceTypeV2.GetAll(params)
        .subscribe({
            next: (result: ServiceType[]) => {

             
               this.serviceType = result.sort((a, b) => a.value- b.value);
                console.log(result);

            },
            error: (e) => console.error(e)
        });
}

  editServicesV(servicetype:ServiceType[]){
        // this.editServiceType();
        this.formToSelectedService();


        this.serviceTypeV2.UpdateService(servicetype).subscribe({
            next: (res: ServiceType[]) =>{
                console.log(res);

            }
        })
        this.loadServicesV2();

    }



i've also tried other methods to test the edit:
service :
 Update(ServiceDtoToSave : any): Observable<ServiceType>{
    let servTypeServiceDtoToSave: ServiceType = this.mapObjectToSave(ServiceDtoToSave);
        return this.httpClient.put<ServiceType>(`${(this.SERVICE_TYPE_CONTEXT)}` , servTypeServiceDtoToSave); 


    mapObjectToSave(serviceTypeDto: any): ServiceType{
        let ServiceDtoToSave : ServiceType = new ServiceType();
        serviceTypeDto.value? ServiceDtoToSave.value = serviceTypeDto.value:null;
        ServiceDtoToSave.name = serviceTypeDto.name;
        ServiceDtoToSave.minFwVersion = serviceTypeDto.minFwVersion;
         ServiceDtoToSave.compatIcan = serviceTypeDto.compatIcan;
        ServiceDtoToSave.compatIcanne = serviceTypeDto.compatIcanne;
        ServiceDtoToSave.compatIcanpl = serviceTypeDto.compatIcanpl;
        ServiceDtoToSave.compatIcanv2 = serviceTypeDto.compatIcanv2;
        ServiceDtoToSave.attributesService = [];
        ServiceDtoToSave?.attributesService.forEach(attribute=> {
            ServiceDtoToSave.attributesService.push({
                name : attribute.name,
                value : attribute.value
            })});

        return ServiceDtoToSave;
    }


component.ts:
editServicesV1(servicetype:ServiceType[]){
        // this.editServiceType();
       // this.formToSelectedService();


        this.serviceTypeV2.Update(servicetype).subscribe({
            next: (res: ServiceType[]) =>{
                console.log(res);
                this.formToSelectedService();
            }
        })
        this.loadServicesV2();

    }

